# Python pywinauto for Mac for Audacity

Tags: python, macos, pip, pywinauto, win32-process

I have a working code on Windows which, after a bunch of many other steps, uses Audacity to de-noise the received audio file. I had been using the following code on Windows to transfer control to perform a set of actions:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import application

def noiseReduce(filename):
    app = application.Application()
    app = app.connect(path=r'/Applications/Audacity')
    app.captcha20170411_202241.menu_select('File->Import->Audio')
    app.Selectoneormoreaudiofiles.Edit.SetText(filename + '.wav')
```

I ported this code to my Mac and installed the necessary Py modules like pywinauto. However, I am getting this error:

```
File "/Users/gautam/PycharmProjects/project/Capture.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pywinauto import application
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pywinauto/application.py", line 75, in <module>
    import win32process
ImportError: No module named 'win32process'
```

On trying to pip install win32process, I am getting an error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32process
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for win32process

Is there a way to resolve this or another alternative to transfer control to Audacity and perform actions on it?

Answer (score 3):

Currently pywinauto doesn't support Apple Accessibility API and shouldn't work on MacOS.

Unfortunately there is no good cross-platform GUI automation tool (using accessibility text-based approach) in the open source field. The only one is LDTP (Linux Desktop Testing Project) and API-compatible Cobra (on Windows) and pyatom (MacOS). Fortunately [pyatom](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom) is a standalone self-contained library as well. My students were able to automate few apps using pyatom. You may consider using it for now.

P.S. We're trying to make pywinauto cross-platform (with real seamless integration), but MacOS backend implementation is on the very early development stage for now. I expect to introduce Linux AT-SPI support earlier than Apple Accessibility API one.

Comment: Any update on the linux & apple support. Or is there any link that we can follow for updates?

Comment: Linux support has some beta quality at branch `atspi`, latest macOS branch is here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/1213